# how to set my graph to be side bar graph

Tags: delphi

while not sqlDebtors.eof do begin
      fAmtOut := 0;
      fAmt := 0;
      sBranch := sqlDebtors.fieldbyname('Branch').AsString;
      while (not sqlDebtors.Eof) and (sqlDebtors.FieldByName('Branch').AsString             =sBranch) do begin
         fAmtOut := fAmtOut + sqlDebtors.fieldbyname('Outstanding').asfloat;
         fAmt := fAmt + sqlDebtors.fieldbyname('Amount').asfloat;
         sqlDebtors.Next;
      end;
      pbar.add(fAmtOut, sBranch);
      pbar.add(fAmt, sBranch);
    end;

my graph draw like this
[image]

but i want to group my graph to be side bar graph so its can group by branch like this:
[image]

hope anyone can help me.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pBar.MultiBar := mbSide;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two BarSeries. So just add another one, let's say pBar2 (either in code or in the Designer).
then just

```
pbar.add(fAmtOut, sBranch);
pbar2.add(fAmt, sBranch);
```

You may also want to set the colors of each series, soemthing like this:

```
pbar.colorEach:=false;
pbar2.colorEach:=false;
pbar.Color:=clRed;
pbar2.Color:=clGreen;
```